# switch statements; decimal precision

Tags: java, switch-statement, precision

I'm unsure of how I would create a switch statement that used decimal precision, as switch statements are incompatible with double date types.

```
 double grade = input.nextDouble(); //read grade

    while (grade !=-1)
    {
        total += grade; // add grade total
        ++gradeCounter; // increment number of grades

        // increment appropriate letter-grade counter
        switch (grade / 1)
        {
            case 92.5: // grade was between 90
            case 100: // and 100, inclusive
                ++aCount;
                break; // exits Switch
```

is the specific part of the code that I'm having trouble with, but I'm not sure what I change the switch with.

It's in the Java language, and I'm using the Netbeans IDE, if that information is needed.

Comment: Yes. I'm using NetBeans IDE as well, in case this changes anything.

Comment: What you are illustrating is not well-suited to a switch statement. Would encourage you to use `if`

Comment: All right. I had thought using a switch statement would be more compact. Thank you.

Comment: The core issue that makes it unsuitable is that you are dealing with a range, and the switch cases are based on a discrete value.

Comment: @F.Helix Many people consider "switch" statements to be one of the things you should avoid at all cost any way. If at all, you hide the switch part within one class; and build polymorphism around it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert to int, but make a multiplication first to don't lose decimal point.

```
double grade = 92.5;

int convertedGrade = (int) (grade * 10);

switch(convertedGrade) {

case 925: System.out.println("Grade is 92.5");
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, a `switch-case` statement is intended to be used with discrete/enumerable values, which makes it incompatible with the `double` data type. If I understood the idea correctly, and you would want your program to nicely convert exam points into grades, you could use an `enum` that defines the minimum points for each grade:

```
enum Grade {

    A(92.5), B(82.5), C(72.5), D(62.5), E(52.5), F(0.0);

    private static final Grade[] GRADES = values();
    private double minPoints;

    Grade(double minPoints) {
        this.minPoints = minPoints;
    }

    public static Grade forPoints(double points) {
        for (Grade g : GRADES) {
            if (points >= g.minPoints) {
                return g;
            }
        }
        return F;
    }
}
```

The `forPoints()` method in `Grade` allows you to lookup the grade that correcponds to the exam points.

Now, to keep track of the number of grades, you could use an `EnumMap<Grade, Integer>` instead of individual counter variables. Note that because the lookup is coded into the `enum`, you no longer need a `switch-case`:

```
Map<Grade, Integer> gradeCounters = new EnumMap<>(Grade.class);

// initialize the counters
for(Grade g : Grade.values()) {
    gradeCounters.put(g, 0);
}

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
double total = 0;
int gradeCounter = 0; 
double points = input.nextDouble(); //read exam points

while (points >= 0) {
    total += points; // add points to total
    ++gradeCounter; // increment number of grades

    // increment appropriate letter-grade counter
    Grade g = Grade.forPoints(points);
    int currentCount = gradeCounters.get(g);
    gradeCounters.put(g, currentCount + 1);

    points = input.nextDouble();
}
```